# \regex_match is not working as expected

Tags: expl3, latex3, parsing, regex

I have the following macro and the following input:

```
\def\something#1{
    \regex_extract_all:nnN{
            ([A-Za-z]{1}\d{1,2})\s*-\|\s*([A-Za-z]{1}\d{1,2})
        }{#1}\l_my_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn\l_my_seq{##1,\par}
}

\something{A1-|B2-|C3}
```

The issue is that I only extract A1 and B2, and not B2 and C3. What is wrong with the regular expression?

[image]

Comment: I guess this goes under the name “backtracking”, which isn't implemented in l3regex

Comment: Please always provide a complete _minimal working example_ instead of code snippets. Here _working_ is to say that it should be a complete document that can be copied and compiled as is, so people can test your code without having to add (and sometimes guess) what's missing to make it run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken on what `\regex_extract_all:nnN` does. Consider this simpler example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \def\something#1{
      \regex_extract_all:nnN{..}{#1}\l_my_seq
      \seq_map_inline:Nn\l_my_seq{##1,~}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\something{abcdefg}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

As you can see, `bc`, `de` or `fg` are never found. This is the usual behavior of regular expression searches: No part of the input string is part of multiple matches. Rather, after finding a match, the search engine discards any consumed part of the input string and continues searching after the match.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The explanation and example are very clear.